# Null error while unit testing for webcontrols

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to unit test the function

```
int add(a,b)
{
  int c = txtInputBox.value;
  int d = a+b+c;
  return d;
}
```

here, I am just passing the values a and b. I am not passing the value for C. It's taking from a textbox.

When I call the function in my web application project, the function works fine since I taking the value of C from the aspx page control.

But when I run this function from the unit test project, text box control fail as the page will not get loaded, so the textbox also will not get loaded. The function add(a,b) is executed through unit test project.

> Hence, txtInputBox  will be null

This the unit test goes to a debug error, null exception and unit test go to catch and the unit test fails.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Rather than having your add() function rely on a UI control, why not just pass in a third parameter c and let the calling code get the value c from the txtInputBox. That way you separate your code from your form implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using MS Unit Test Project for doing this. First and foremost thing is that MS Unit Test wouldn't be able to test anything related to UI, for which, we have Code UI Tests. And coming to your question, you should consider moving out the code accessing Textbox (or any UI elements for that matter). Consider passing it as a parameter to this function as shown below.

```
public int Add (int a, int b, int c)
{
   // Do Something
}
```

Hope this Helps!!